# Implement OpenCV for Image Marker detecting

Tags: swift, opencv, image-recognition

i have set up an app using OpenCV framework, to detect an image marker with the camera, and then react if the image on the screen matches the marker.
So far i have gotten quite a way by following:

https://medium.com/@dwayneforde/image-recognition-on-ios-with-swift-and-opencv-b5cf0667b79

And have also used his code, to implement the image-matching-function. Everything is set up, and i should be ready to go... but... The app crashes when it try to run the application.

The problem lies where i check for matches. I use this code as instructed in the tutorial:

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)img {
cv::Mat gimg;

// Convert incoming img to greyscale to match template
cv::cvtColor(img, gimg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Use check for matches with a certain threshold to help with scaling and angles
cv::Mat res(img.rows-gtpl.rows+1, gtpl.cols-gtpl.cols+1, CV_32FC1);
cv::matchTemplate(gimg, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
cv::threshold(res, res, 0.5, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.9;
cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
cv::minMaxLoc(res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

// If it's a good enough match
if (maxval >= threshold)
{
    // Draw a rectangle for confirmation
    cv::rectangle(img, maxloc, cv::Point(maxloc.x + gtpl.cols, maxloc.y + gtpl.rows), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2);
    cv::floodFill(res, maxloc, cv::Scalar(0), 0, cv::Scalar(.1), cv::Scalar(1.));
    
    // Call our delegates callback method
    [delegate matchedItem];
}
```

}

The problem seems to be with the line:

```
  cv::matchTemplate(gimg, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

And i get this error-message:

> OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1) in crossCorr, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 589
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.1) /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:589: error: (-215) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function crossCorr

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try the code as shared here: https://github.com/osis/nostalgia-scanner-ios

Comment: The code is exact as the shared code :-(